# adding helping comments to the jar file

Tags: java, cmd, jar

How can I comments to the jar file, like for example, When we use

```
java -h
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
```

How can I add this feature to my jar file so that, when someone uses the command help on my jar file, he gets some custom information. Like

```
myjar.jar -h
Should display some custom information.
```

Comment: Either make your `main` parse the `String[] args` accordingly or use something like `args4j`.

Comment: `if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("-h")) printHelp();` (and then you probably want to call `System.exit`).